# Desktop Completely Freezes When Accessing Wi-Fi Hotspot

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, arch-linux, manjaro

I installed Manjaro 16.10.3 Xfce yesterday and everything was fine. I use a Wi-Fi adapter to create a hotspot from my desktop PC. It worked without any problem. The problem started after the update. Now, when I try to access Wi-Fi from my phone, the desktop freezes completely. Keyboard, mouse, everything stopped. I can't even turn on/off “Num Lock”.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarted the Network Manager by the following command and problem solved:

`systemctl restart NetworkManager.service`